# trigger in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I've been researching but I just can't seem to get it right. 
I have the following tables:

```
create table school_tb
(idSchool int identity primary key,
nameSchool varchar(100),
schoolPopulation int
)

create table career_tb
(idCareer int identity primary key,
nameCareer       varchar(100),
carrerPopulation int,
numberClasses    int, 
idSchool int foreign key references school_tb(idSchool)
)
```

to find out the populatuon in the first table I have to SUM() population from the careers in the same school.
I need to create a trigger that will update the column population in table school_tb when I update population in career_tb. please help me. 
I had something like this, but I can't get it to work.

```
--create trigger updatePopulation
--on career_tb
--for update as
--if UPDATE(carrerPopulation)
--update school_tb set schoolPopulation =(SELECT add(carrerPopulation)
--                                  from career_tb
--                                  where idSchool=(SELECT idSchool
--                                  from career_tb
--                                  where idCareer=@idCareer)
--                                  )
--go
```

I appreciate any help given. thanks

Comment: BTW I'm using sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out. Please see the comments inside the body of a trigger.

```
create trigger updatePopulation
on career_tb
-- to update sum even if carreer gets deleted or inserted
after insert, update, delete
as
-- to avoid trigger messing up rows affected
   set nocount on

   if UPDATE(carrerPopulation)
   begin
    -- update sum by difference between previous and current state of one record in career
      update school_tb
         set schoolPopulation = schoolPopulation + difference
        from school_tb
      -- derived table sums all the careers changed in one go
         inner join
         (
         -- sum all values from careers by school
             select idSchool, sum (carrerPopulation) difference
             from
             (
              -- change sign of previous values
                 select deleted.idSchool, -deleted.carrerPopulation carrerPopulation
                   from deleted
                 union all
              -- + current values
                 select inserted.idSchool, inserted.carrerPopulation
                   from inserted
              ) a
              group by idSchool
            -- Skip update in case of no change
              having sum (carrerPopulation) <> 0
         ) a
           on school_tb.idSchool = a.idSchool
    end
```

Comment: hello. thanks. for the quick answer, been trying your answer but still does not work in the select before selecting the deleted and inserted values, is saying invalid column name :S I really appreciate your answer tho. thank you

Comment: I've changed my response a bit, please try again.

Comment: I'm getting this now Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure updatePopulation, Line 30
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'a'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updatePopulation, Line 32
Invalid column name 'carrerPopulation'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure updatePopulation, Line 19
Invalid column name 'carrerPopulation'.

Comment: And again... I forgot to alias -deleted.careerPopulation.

Comment: it puts a negative number in the column... sight I'm so frustrated, do you know how can  I learn all of this complex query's?

Comment: First you need to set schoolPopulation to sum(carrerPopulation) because it is probably out of sync. *update school_tb set schoolPopulation = (select sum(carrerPopulation) from career_tb where career_tb.idSchool = school_tb.idSchool).* Then try to insert new career row, because this trigger, as the one from Oleg Dok, work by adding difference, not by suming everything. As for complex queries, they are nothing but simple queries linked together, and you should see them as such. Break complex task into series of smaller. Makes it easier to see what you do not know.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER name ON career_tb
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE school_tb T
    USING
    (
        SELECT idSchool, SUM(carrerPopulation) res
        FROM
        (
            SELECT idSchool, carrerPopulation
            FROM INSERTED
            UNION ALL
            SELECT idSchool, -carrerPopulation
            FROM DELETED
        ) t
        GROUP BY idSchool
    ) S
    ON T.idSchool = S.idSchool
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        schoolPopulation = T.schoolPopulation  +S.res
    ;


END
```

Comment: I tried the coded, didn't work either it says incorrect syntax near 'after' tried taking it off, and it tells me 'the object career_tb does not exist or is invalid (and it does exists) thanks for the quick answer I appreciate it

Comment: hi. I added the following code to your answer 'If update(poblacion)' and it allowed me to create the trigger but it's updating the schoolPopulation value with a crazy number. for example -9990 when I updated one career to 1000 careerPopulation

Comment: @itsmedavid Corrected, and i think you should strip off the `If update(population)` - or check if it surely works on deletes.